# How to use multiple changesets at the same page

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have to update 3 tables at the same time.
One page has 3 changesets.

If I post 3 chagnesets with `form_for`, how can I write code?
The 3 tables are following.

```
---------
 members
---------
id
name

----------------
 member_details  
----------------
member_id
address
phone_no

--------------
 member_items
--------------
member_id
item_id
```

Or another way will be welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

I felt in a similar problem as you. You don't need 3 Changesets. What you need is an `embedded_schema` that contains the 3 top elements you're trying to insert. Then when you submit the form you can call each of the changesets corresponding to the element you're trying to insert. Finally you make use of Ecto.Multi or Repo.transaction in other to make this operation all fail or all succeed. Have a look at the top description (specifically the SignUp example) of the documentation of schema on how this works. https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html

Comment: My issue are if I get parameter from previous page with form `create(conn, %{"xxx" => params})`, I need to use form `f`. But if I get parameters with `create(conn, params)` with 3 changesets,  I don't know how to insert db them.

Comment: let say you created an embedded_schema `group` which has `member`, `member_details` and `member_items`. In your controller you pattern match on `create(conn, %{"group" => group} = params)`. The next thing to do is to call Each of the changesets, e.g: `MemberItems.changeset(%MemberItem{}, group["member_items"])`... then using a transaction you insert them all.

Comment: RE: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/embedded-schemas.html#user-profile-example. This doesn't work when preloading is required, like w/ `many-to-many`. Doing `Repo.preload(:users)` will fail b/c the embedded schema `profile` doesn't exist on the users table, but it DOES exist on the user schema, i.e %User{} will have a field `profile` on it. Is there anyway to remove this, after the fact? It's a big problem for me atm.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want the tables to be either all updated or not, this required a transaction. The perfect use-case for [`Ecto.Multi`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#content). There is [the example](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#module-example) that you might directly apply to your case.

To split incoming params to three sets, one would probably use [`Map.take/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html?#take/2).

Comment: Probably I need to know how to make `changeset` for presetting in `new action` and `new.html.eex`. I was trying but I have no idea.

Comment: I might need to make like `Xxx.changet(xxx, %{})` for 3 tables.

Comment: I do not follow. It does not matter when you create the changeset—it’s always done the same way, your schemas accept `params` (splitter as I said above) and produce a changeset as shown [everywhere in docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html?#module-validations-and-constraints)).

Comment: _I might need to make like `Xxx.changet(xxx, %{})` for 3 tables._ Exactly. I do not see any issue here.

Comment: My issue is how to give 3 changesets in `@changeset` for parameter to `form_for`. or how to set 3 changesets in `changeset` in action.

Comment: I have no idea about phoenix (and what `@changeset` parameter is ever needed for,) but a quick search showed up the `as:` option in a call to [`Phoenix.HTML.Form.form_for/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html?#form_for/4-options). This way you might specify how to get to what was send back on the server side. Then split and you are all set.

Comment: Thank you for giving me advice. Finally I found `form_tag`. It might be easier for me from RoR.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue in an onboarding flow that involved multiple models. I found the example in Ecto docs about data mapping and validation to be most helpful.

https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/data-mapping-and-validation.html#content

Here is a quick **tl;dr** of the approach

1. Create a new onboarding context to hold my logic
2. created a [schemaless changeset](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#module-schemaless-changesets)
3. Use the schemaless changset in `mount` so it is available the phoenix form.
4. Add the `as:` option in the form. It doesn't really matter what the key is.
5. On submit, evaluate if my schemaless changeset is true:

   - invalid, return an error changeset - be careful to append the `action` to this changeset. Without this, the phoenix form won't display error messages. Example: `%{form_changeset | action: :insert}`
   - valid, execute storing the records with Ecto.Multi, probably using the same changesets you'd use in other insert/update operations. Return whatever you would normally return to the LiveView

The big downside for me was duplicated validation logic. I added some tests to maintain consistent validations between my schemaless changset and the "normal" validations I'm using in my Ecto.Multi.